# reading data from csv file and writing to excel using phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, vlookup, phpspreadsheet

I need a phpspreadsheet code for reading data from csv file using vlookup and then writing it to multiple xlsx file depending on the criteria

Example:
**Reading from this file**
[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PrIA.png)
**Getting output like this:**
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Qkq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend the PhpSpreadsheet library, it's free and has great documentation on how to do this exact sort of thing.

Comment: I know very little in coding. It would be helpful if you can write it.

Comment: Well this website is not designed to search for free software development outsourcing. I'd recommend you hire a developer.